# document.getElementById("ID").focus() + Google Chrome

Tags: javascript

document.getElementById("ID").focus() not work in Google Chrome. Is there any alternative? Thank you.

Comment: It seem to work just fine with text fields. What kind of element do you try to focus?

Comment: What do you *mean* it doesn't work? Give an example, please!

Comment: Are you sure of this, it works for me.

Comment: Also just in-case, try not to use keywords when giving names or ids. I feel like I've had that be a problem in IE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to focus something that can't normally be focused you might need to add a tabindex:

```
<span id="something" tabindex="0">Something</span>

document.getElementById("something").focus()
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it does work, so I'd suggest that you verify that your `ID` is correct and that `document.getElementById()` is returning the element that you were expecting.